# Can't connect to backend with iOS Beta App

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, backend

When I run the app in a simulator or device connected to the laptop to test via XCode, everything works well and there is interaction with backend. As soon as I distribute the app and make it available via TestFlight or App Distribution, it does not connect with backend. The API can be accessed with PostMan and some APIs are not protected, so I'm using those to test if something is coming through or not. Is there some kind of configuration I should be aware of?

Comment: The most probable is that the device can not find the computer on network to connect to : is it accessed via up address ? (Private network ?) Is it addressed via name ? (Local network name) .  Can you access via TestFlight and device on local network ?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong environment variables. Development variables instead of production variables, so it kept deploying using localhost:8000 as backend.